# Google Calendar API ACL Rule Not Sending Invitation to Non-Google Email Address

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

We're looking for some specific expertise with respect to sharing access to Google Calendar accounts via the Google Calendar v3 API.  Once the calendar is created, we are creating ACL rules to allow access by other email addresses.  Our problem lies in having the auto-generated invitation sent to non-Google email addresses.  Unlike a Gmail address, which automatically gets the calendar added to the Gmail address' calendar, we've found that if the email address has not been previously linked to a Google account, it does not automatically receive an invite from Google to the Calendar as it would if the the address was shared manually via the web browser interface.  We are able to manually have the invitation sent out by manually deleting the API created ACL rule from the calendar's share list and then manually adding the email address again, which prompts to send the invitation.  Naturally, we want that invitation sent automatically when the ACL rule is added by the API.

Note, this has nothing to do with sending event notifications. This is for access to view the calendar itself.

Is there anyone with some relevant experience that can enlighten us on this behaviour?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: 2 years later and I'm having the same issue